# ASP.NET MVC - Can't access a parent class in a database relationship (LINQ TO SQL)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have a class **User** and a class **History**. History has 'User' property, and User has 'Histories' property. So there's a database relationship.

But when I create a new User history class and set UserID property, I can't access the 'User' property.

```
var history = new History { UserID = 1 };
// history.User = null ???
```

How can I get the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to create a new `User` and then set the `UserID` property:

```
var history = new History();

history.User = new User { UserID = 1 };
```

Comment: +1 My own model classes would work this way.  Setting the relational key (UserId) will not load the related object (User).  Getting the full user object would be a data access operation and not supported in the model.